# HABTM find, how to filter the results

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

Ive a HABTM relationship where the output is like below, what i would like to do is have cakephp return a "list" with just the "friend.id" and "friend.company_name" and exclude the "User".

Ive spent quite a while researching how to do this and cant get it to work.

My "search method" in users controller; i think i need to use the containable behaviour but im not sure what to do. ive managed to get the "friend" results only show 2 fields but i need to get rid of the "User" results. How do i do this?

The relationship is defined as in the user model file;

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
'Friend' => array(
    'joinTable' => 'retailerrelationships',
    'className' => 'User',
    'foreignKey' => 'retailer_id',
    'associationForeignKey' => 'supplier_id'
)
    );
```

user action in user controller:

```
$this->User->Behaviors->attach('Containable');

$users=$this->User->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$this->Auth->user('id')),'contain'=>array('Friend.id','Friend.company_name')));         
        $this->set('users' ,$users);
```

debug Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 104
                    [username] => admin                    
                )

            [Friend] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 107
                            [company_name] => carskitchens
                            [Retailerrelationship] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 12
                                    [retailer_id] => 104
                                    [supplier_id] => 107
                                    [created] => 2012-03-28 10:14:23
                                    [modified] => 2012-03-28 10:14:23
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 112
                            [company_name] => mr manufacturer
                            [Retailerrelationship] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 13
                                    [retailer_id] => 104
                                    [supplier_id] => 112
                                    [created] => 2012-03-28 11:26:52
                                    [modified] => 2012-03-28 11:26:52
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the [`Set`](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/set) class.

Try this

```
Set::combine($results, '{n}.Friend.id', '{n}.Friend.company_name');
```

Comment: Can you go into more detail? First, I used `$results` instead of your `$users` var. Also, you need to assign it so `$options = Set::combine...`, etc. Did you debug the output to see what it gave you?

Comment: actually you were right my bad i changed my find to "first" and its working thanks